# Implementing FTP in Java - Connecting to port specified in 227 response to PASV command

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, network-programming

I am trying to program a FTP client and I can't seem to connect to the passive ports. I want to eventually list directories and download a file but I don't know how to do that either.

This is what my program is printing out.

```
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (73,13,156,129,217,103).
Passive Ports: 73,13,156,129,217,103
Failed to connect to port: 73
Failed to connect to port: 13
Failed to connect to port: 156
Failed to connect to port: 129
Failed to connect to port: 217
Failed to connect to port: 103
"/home/daniel">>
```

---

```
case 227://PASSIVE MODE
    String psPorts = lastMessage.substring(lastMessage.indexOf('(')+1,lastMessage.indexOf(')'));
    System.out.println("Passive Ports: " + psPorts);
    for(String i : psPorts.split(",")){
        Ports.add(Integer.parseInt(i));
    }

    for(int i: Ports){
        try{
            pSk = new Socket("webserver",i);
            break;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to port: " + i);
        }
    }
    break;
```

Can someone please help me? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers in `227` response to the `PASV` command are not port numbers.

The format is:

```
IP_A,IP_B,IP_C,IP_D,PORT_HI,PORT_LO
```

So you need yo connect to

```
pSk = new Socket("IP_A.IP_B.IP_C.IP_D", PORT_HI<<8 + PORT_LO);
```

The above is a pseudo code (I do not do Java).